# Import custom vue component in main.js file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have lots of Vue components. I want to set up routing for them from the main.js file. But I'm unable to import my component here as it is a javascript file. How can I import my Vue component(.vue) here?

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

// Components importing
import LandingPage './components/LandingPage.vue'; // error occurs here

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: LandingPage },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to import like

```
import { LandingPage } './components/LandingPage.vue'
```

Or

make export default to `LandingPage` component.